# running java and javac on start

Tags: shell, java, shell-script, deb

I was wondering how can I run the command javac and java on a .java file that is located in /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_121/Testapp.java on boot. So every time the pc is turned on I need the java file to be compiled and then run. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, you're running Debian or Ubuntu.

If you're on recent system with [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), just create [systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) file, called  `/etc/systemd/system/java-test-app.unit` in this example.

```
[Unit]
Description = Java test app
After = network.target
Wants = network.target

[Service]
Type = oneshot
User = myuser
Workdir = /home/myuser
ExecStartPre = javac Testapp.java
ExecStart = java Testapp

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

I recommend to create separate user for the app (called `myuser` in this example), because running applications as root is usually not good idea.

I would also suggest to move the application out of Java distribution as the directory `/usr/lib` is usually maintained by packaging system and not by regular user.

After creating the unit file, try it to make sure it works.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start java-test-app
```

To make the application to start after system boot.

```
systemctl enable java-test-app
```

You can check the app execution with

```
systemctl status java-test-app
```

If you want to run the app as root, just update the appropriate linec in the unit file.